# Need a simple APP or Software or Tool for auto typing

Tags: windows-7, text-editors, typing, typing-speed

I'm looking for an application which can do something as follows -

In a notepad or any editor, if I go on hitting any keystrokes, it shall go on typing only predefined text in an application.

For e.g.

If I specify following text block in the software :

```
<?php 
for($a=0;$a<10;$a++){
echo $a.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

Now what happen is, above codeblock/textblock is already specified in the software I'm looking for. When I open notepad and no matter what keystrokes I'm typing, it shall go on typing one char per keystroke from above block into the editor. So it is like text is being inserted per keystroke.

I need such facility for my presentations. It involves writing many lines of code blocks into the editor. So this way I can still have much much realistic effect of actual code typing in my presentation.

1. Please visit this url : http://www.google.com/intl/en/+/demo/
2. Click on Huddle.
3. In the phone text typing area, if you go on hitting any keystrokes, it will type one char automatically from predefined text. I'm looking for such facility on editor in windows for much bigger texts.

Comment: In your code, use semicolons in the for loop, not commas :)

Answer (score 1):

I found [fake notepad](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Fun/Fake-Notepad.shtml). Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know of any tool that does exactly what you wanted, especially the *Ignore my input and instead enter what I have configured* request.

However, you could  *misuse* User Interface Automation tools that are normally used to test applications. Here’s a list of programs on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools).

The best from this list for you question seems to be AutoHotkey (for an overview, see [this tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.net/~Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/docs/Tutorial.htm)).

In your example, you would set up a hotkey that enters the URL and another one that enters the text. The other steps (Opening the browser and clicking on Huddle) would still be manual steps but I think this does not hurt.